# Как рандомно заполнить таблицу?

Tags: mysql

Как рандомно заполнить таблицу, состоящую из 3 колонок, колонки имеют такие типы:

1. `int(10) AUTO_INCREMENT` - его заполнять не надо
2. `varchar(150)`
3. `date`

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: @Роман Этот вопрос лучше задать на форуме [ХэшКод](hashcode.ru).

Answer (score 1):

Если база в MySQL, на питоне можно сделать так (apt-get install python-mysqldb):

```
import stringimport randomimport datetimeimport MySQLdbmaxlen = 250nrecords = 1000def main():    db = MySQLdb.connect(host = "127.0.0.1", user = "user_name", passwd = "user_pass", db = "test")    cursor = db.cursor()    for item in xrange(nrecords):        name = "".join(random.choice(string.letters) for i in xrange(maxlen))        date = datetime.datetime.now()        sql = "INSERT INTO TABLE1 (NAME, DATE) VALUES (\"%s\", \"%s\")" % (name, date)        cursor.execute(sql)    cursor.close()    db.close()if __name__ == "__main__":    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE table SET field=RAND()